# Classification of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Is it true that all extension of field $k$ are subfields of $\bar k$ (algebraic closure of $k$)? The same question for all **algebraic** extension.

Thanks.

Comment: (a) Let $k$ be the rationals. Are the complex numbers a subfield of the algebraic numbers? Indeed for every $k$ there are extension fields of $k$ that are not isomorphic to $\overline{k}$.  (b) Up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All algebraic extensions of $k$ will embed in $\bar k$ over $k$. It's easy to do this for something like $k(\alpha)$ with $\alpha$ algebraic over $k$ [One way to think about this: $k(\alpha)$ is isomorphic to $k[X]/(f)$, where $f$ is the irreducible polynomial of $\alpha$ over $k$; what does it mean to give a homomorphism of $k$-algebras $k[X]/(f) \to \bar{k}$?], and you can prove it for arbitrary algebraic extensions using Zorn's lemma. You can read the proof in, for example, [Milne's notes](http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html), Theorem 6.6.

On the other hand, there will always be extensions of $k$ that are not algebraic — these are the [transcendental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_element) extensions. These fields have elements, such as $X$ in the field of [rational functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Abstract_algebra_and_geometric_notion) $k(X)$, that do not satisfy any polynomial with coefficients in $k$. An embedding of such a field into $\bar k$ over $k$ would contradict this last property.

Comment: For a concrete example, $\mathbb R$ is an extension of $\mathbb Q$ but is not an *algebraic* extension of $\mathbb Q$.